# show result of date_diff in seconds

Tags: php, datediff

I have 2 Unix timestamp values . I need to find the difference  between them and the result should be in Seconds.

I used the following code to calculate the difference.

```
<?php 
$diff = date_diff(  new DateTime($timestamp1), new DateTime($timestamp12));
echo $diff->format('%y%m%d%i%s');
?>
```

Could you please indicate a better way of doing this?

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 2):

timestamp is number of seconds, so you don't even need `date_diff`.
just use `$timestamp12 - $timestamp1`

Answer (score 1):

To get the difference in seconds, take advantage from the fact that the UNIX timestamp is already in seconds - it will just be the difference between those integers:

```
$diff_in_seconds = $timestamp12 - $timestamp1;
```

Reading from Wikipedia:

> Unix time (also known as POSIX time or Epoch time) is a system for
>   describing instants in time, defined as the number of seconds that
>   have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC),
>   Thursday, 1 January 1970